# Migrar base de datos MongoDB a MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mongodb, exportar

¿Cómo podría migrar una base de datos desde MongoDB a MySQL?

Hasta ahora he realizado diferentes búsquedas y no lo tengo muy claro. Por cierto ¿desde phpmyadmin habría alguna posibilidad?

Comment: y no.. no lo vas a tener claro, porque una es una base de datos no relacional, y la otra es una base de datos relacional... no es algo que podamos contestar asi livianamente....

Comment: gbianchi tiene razón pero es posible que sea sencilo, dependiendo de la complejidad de las tablas que tengas. Tendrías que crear un código (por ejemplo en php) que lea los registros de cada tabla y te los devuelva en formato JSON. Luego solo tendrías que importar ese JSON en mongodb.

Comment: @Fedex7501 Pero lo que el OP requiere es al reves, pasar de mongo a mysql, por lo tanto depende 100% de la estructura que tenga el en mongo para saber como intentar migrar eso a MySQL... pero inicialmente pensaría que es un camello (en caso de que las colecciones tengan objetos complejos)

Comment: @Pipe ah leí mal. Entonces sí puede estar más complicado. Especialmente si usó arreglos de objetos u otras estructuras complejas

Comment: Si, tal cual... eso se le podría convertir en un mounstruo lleno de Joins